# Dell Inspiron 3543 Intel HD Graphics - Installation, display problems

Tags: display

While trying to install Elementary OS on my DELL 15 3543 there's serious problem with display.  Captions are missing, icons are not displayed.. same is happening while using OS as live CD (or USB).

[image: Display problems]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/596393/thinkpad-t450s-intel-hd-graphics-5500-ubuntu-14-04-unstable). Go through this. According to the only answer-a kernel upgrade will solve the problem, which is expected since the kernel upgrade comes with a newer 3.19 kernel with updated Intel graphics drivers. So I would suggest 2 things:

1. Don't install Elementary OS yet and try something else (like Ubuntu 15.04) with a newer kernel. Try a LiveUSB/CD and see if it works properly. Its better to wait for the Elementary team to let their system upgrade to a newer kernel so that it is nicely supported on all sides.
2. Try installing it on the laptop somehow and then upgrade the kernel following [this](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/linux-kernel-3-19-3-released-install-update-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-other-debian-based-distros) guide. But I **do not** recommend this since after the upgrade you do not get security bug fixes(from Ubuntu security repos) and any problems(due to untested kernel) and bugs will not guarantee any support from the elementary team. But if you are feeling adventurous, go ahead. At your own risk. :)

Comment: Thanks, actually yestraday I tried the first option with latest Ubuntu and it works fine. It seems I have to wait for new release of elementary.

Comment: Good to see that it helped you. Why don't you mark my answer as the most helpful one (that green tick mark)? It would help anyone else who has the same problem.

Comment: Already done, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install with nomodeset option, to prevent kernel load a wrong graphic driver.

Start your laptop from usb. When you see the grub boot menu, use your down arrow and go to "Install elementary OS " and rather than press enter key, press "e" key.

Now, you can see the boot options. Use your down arrow again and go to a line that look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Add "nomodeset" after "splash":

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Then press ctrl + X to boot the new grub entry.

After install elementary OS,  you will can configure your graphic driver.

Comment: Hi, nomodeset option didn't help, still getting display problems during install or live CD.

Comment: Add "i915.modeset=0" before "nomodeset" and try again. Feedback will be aprecciated.

Comment: I'm getting black screen with mouse cursor only.

Comment: Change "i915.modeset=0" with "xforcevesa" and feedback,  please

Comment: No change, black screen with mouse coursor. During boot theres message "cannot turn on display power on i915"

Comment: Please,  change to "quiet splash video=i915:modeset=1" and feedback